# Ruby RVM issues

Tags: ruby, rvm

So I think* RVM may be keeping my Ruby version back artificially. I am getting all sorts of errors in Rails. So I checked the Ruby version I was using. Said it was back a few versions.. so I tried updating to 2.5.0. System said 2.5.0 was already installed? So I checked ruby -v, and got 2.3.3

Here is exactly what my system is telling me:

```
Johns-MacBook-Pro:PLAYGROUND johnseabolt$ brew install ruby
Warning: ruby 2.5.0_2 is already installed
Johns-MacBook-Pro:PLAYGROUND johnseabolt$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]
Johns-MacBook-Pro:PLAYGROUND johnseabolt$
```

I thought it was an RVM issue maybe? But when I tried to use 2.5.0, I got this:

```
Johns-MacBook-Pro:PLAYGROUND johnseabolt$ rvm use 2.5.0_2
Required ruby-2.5.0_2 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install "ruby-2.5.0"'
```

Any ideas what is going on? It's a bit of a pain.

Comment: Installing through homebrew and through RVM are completely separate managers. either manage your ruby version through RVM OR homebrew, not both

Comment: Another developer installed RVM. If I had my choice, I would remove it. Didn't realize it would create this issue. Gotta figure that out

Comment: If it was me, I'd continue with RVM, and stop using homebrew for ruby. (well really I use neither, chruby baby!) you can't switch versions as quickly/easily if you manage it with homebrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the relevant line of output:

```
To install do: 'rvm install "ruby-2.5.0"'
```

what happens when you run that line of code? It should fix all your problems... :)

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help

Comment: You're welcome - sometimes it takes fresh eyes to point out the thing to do. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're saying your problem is exactly, but you can and will have multiple versions of Ruby installed in various places on a modern system. Different applications will require different versions.

In terms of being held back, Ruby doesn't autoupdate like browsers, it's up to you to install the ones you want.

It looks like you have at least one Ruby installed with RVM, and you may have installed with Brew too (which I didn't you know you could do, but I would recommend not to do)

`which ruby` will tell you which Ruby is loaded in a new shell. It should be in an RVM bin.